# Can Varnish cache whole page and load ESI from backend?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to cache the whole content of a page via Varnish 4 and symfony2.
The cached page contains an ESI (user box). 
If the page is not cached I can see that the ESI is loaded from the backend server, but when the page gets cached the ESI is not loaded anymore from the backend and varnish caches the whole page without following the ESI.
Can this be accomplished with Varnish 4?
In case, can anyone post an example of the vcl?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking if you can cache the whole page, including the ESI?  Or if you can cache the page, and then load the ESI each time?

Comment: @marcinx27 I would like to cache the page and load the ESI each time.
I tried it with plain php+varnish and works like a charme. When I use symfony 2.3 and varnish I am not able to do this. It caches everything, ESI included.

Comment: @marcinx27 I created a new post with details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652640/symfony-2-3-varnish-cached-page-does-not-fetch-esi-from-backend